# Associativiy at morphism level in a strict monoidal category

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

The associativity condition in a strict monoidal category is very often defined just at the object level, namely, for objects $x,y,z$ in a strict monoidal category $\mathsf{C}$, one has:

$$(x\otimes y)\otimes z = x\otimes (y\otimes z)$$

Does the associativity at morphism level derive from this condition or is it a part of the definition. As I see, for $f:x\to x'$, $g:y\to y'$ and $h:z\to z'$ the two morphisms $(f\otimes g)\otimes h$ and $f \otimes (g\otimes h)$ share the same source and target objects but are not necessarily the same (what really does *the same* mean in strict case!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are equal. This follows from the naturality of [associator](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/associator#in_monoidal_categories), which is identity in strict monoidal categories.

Comment: Equivalently (I think), strict associativity means not only the equation displayed in the question but also that the associativity isomorphism between the two (equal) sides of that equation is not only an isomorphism but the identity.

Comment: It's true that they are equal in a strict monoidal category, but I think the answer to the question as stated is "no", because this doesn't follow from asserting a simple equality on objects; that equality has to be a "natural equality".

Comment: @AndreasBlass, "the associativity isomorphism between the two (equal) sides of that equation is not only an isomorphism but the identity" this is the difference between a strict monoidal category and a non-strict one, in a non strict one the two objects are merely isomorphic, in a strict one they are equal. Now, I heard someday that isomorphism IS equality...

Comment: @MikeShulman what do you mean by "natural equality"?

Comment: @user62782 I know they are equal, what I don't know is if it is part of the definition or a consequence of the equality at object level

Comment: It is a part of the definition. It requires not only objects to be equal but also associator to be identity. Equality of morphisms follows from the second condition.

Comment: By a "natural equality" I mean a natural transformation whose components are identity morphisms.  This is stronger than just saying that two functors agree on objects.

Comment: Why is this answer the accepted one? It doesn't seem to be correct (namely, when one does not demand the associator to be the identity, but when rather the associator doesn't belong to the data and one just requires the associativity on objects). One should construct a counterexample and post this as an answer.